# How to get value from textfield in PowerPoint into Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

How could this be done?

The PowerPoint application is running and the textfield I want to get the value from is on slide 3.

I've tried this without any success:

```
Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application

Set PPApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

Range("A20").Value = PPApp.Presentation.Slide3.txtMyTextField.Value
```

Anyone know the right way to do this? (I've also added a reference to PowerPoint in the Excel file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes I've got a single TextBox ActiveX Control on my Slide 1.

```
Sub GetTextBoxText()
    Dim ap As Presentation: Set ap = ActivePresentation
    Dim tb As TextBox: Set tb = sl.Shapes(1).OLEFormat.Object
    Debug.Print tb.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot! But I may have been unclear in what i really wanted to do. It's not the regular textfields i want the text from, but the one that is accessed from the developer tab. (Textbox active x control).       And it seems like those cant be handled as shapes? or am i wrong?

Comment: Thanks again! I will check it out shortly.